# How do I update a group of rows excluding the latest item in that group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I need to be able to update every row in my table where a specific field matches, but not the latest row of the matching group.

so lets say for

**Example:**

I have 10 rows:

- 5 rows have the matching field of say, Field1=23
- and the other 5 have a matching field of say, Field1=56

I need to update 4 rows in each matching group leaving the latest item untouched.

No values are fixed, I will not know how many rows there will be or how many groups, the above is just an example.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Add sample data to your question (sqlfiddle would be perfect).

Comment: If you use SQL Server 2008 or later then you could search to use `ROW_NUMBER`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to enumerate rows and a `CTE` to define the to be updated result set. Using the row number you can selectively update the first 4 rows of each partition:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT Field1,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1 ORDER BY myOrderColumnn) AS rn
   FROM mytable
   WHERE Field1 IN (23, 56)
)
UPDATE ToUpdate 
SET Field1 = 'myValue'
WHERE rn <= 4
```

If you need to exclude the last item and you don't know the precise population of each partition then you can reverse the ordering and filter out the first record:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT Field1,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Field1 
                             ORDER BY myOrderColumnn DESC) AS rn
   FROM mytable
   WHERE Field1 IN (23, 56)
)
UPDATE ToUpdate 
SET Field1 = 'myValue'
WHERE rn > 1
```

Comment: Any suggestions for automatically grouping, I cant enter values for each group as with 'WHERE Field1 IN (23, 56)' ?

Comment: @Jack `WHERE` clause is used to filter out unwanted `Field1` values and speed thing up. Grouping is performed inside the `GROUP BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER`, hence you don't need some other way to define groups.

Comment: I just changed it to 'WHERE Field1 IN (SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM myTable)' and it works !

Comment: If you want to do the entire table, just get rid of the 'WHERE Field1 IN' line entirely. It is only useful if you want to do just selected values.